# Set column width in percentage using JQWidgets "setcolumnproperty" method

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqwidget

According to the API documentation of JQWidgets, Width of grid columns can be set in pixel value by "setcolumnproperty" method. Like below

```
$('#jqxGrid').jqxGrid('setcolumnproperty', 'firstname', 'width', 100);
```

But I need it in percentage. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Does the "jqxGrid( {width : " is set in pixel ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct solution as the method "setcolumnproperty" does not support widths as percentages. However, the column properties, such as "width", can be set in percentage when creating the grid as below.

```
$("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
{
    source: dataAdapter,
    columns: [
        { text: 'First Name', datafield: 'firstname', width: '20%'  },
        { text: 'Last Name', datafield: 'lastname', width: '20%' },
        { text: 'Product', datafield: 'productname', width: '20%' }
    ]
});
```

Again the column properties can be passed by an `array` after setting those properties as required.

Comment: actually since 3.2.2, the "setcolumnproperty" method supports width in percentage

Answer (score 0):

instead of 100, you can pass something like "30%"

Comment: "30%" is a percentage value which means that instead of the Number - 100, "30%" or something similar should be passed. if you do not understand my answer, do not comment it!